# Python findall regex issue

Tags: python, regex, findall

So, essentially my main issue comes from the regex part of findall. I'm trying to webscrape some information, but I can't for the life of me get any data to come out correctly. I thought that the (\S+ \S+) was the regex part, and I'd be extracting from any parts in between the HTML code of `<li>` and `</li>`, but instead, I get an empty list from print(data). I realize that I'm going to need a \S+ for every word in each of the list code parts, so how would I go about this? Also, how would I get it to post each one of the different parts of the HTML with the list code parts?

INPUT: Just the website.

Mikky Ekko - Time

OUTPUT: In this case, it should be album titles (i.e. Mikky Ekko - Time)

```
import urllib.request
from re import findall
url = "http://rnbxclusive.se"

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
htmlStr = str(html)

data = findall("<li>(\S+ \S+)</li>.*", htmlStr)
print(data)
for item in data:
   print(item)
```

Comment: The first step in parsing HTML with regular expressions, is to never parse HTML with regular expressions. Use a library like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I wish, but we have to use urllib for our class, and I have no clue how to use BeautifulSoul

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>([^><]*)<\/li>
```

Try this.This will give all contents of `<li>` tag. flag.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/55

Comment: I tried this, but it gave me each line of the HTML, but took out the <li> tags. How does re.DOTALL work?

Comment: `data = findall("<li[^>]*>((?:(?!<\/li>).)*)<\/li>", htmlStr,re.DOTALL)` use this

Comment: For some reason, it says that re is not defined

Comment: Actually, I just imported re, but then I just get the same thing I got before, and if you get rid of `code`from re import findall `code`, you get an error with findall not being defined

Comment: Check the edit I just made. Basically, if I have both `from re import findall` and `import re`, I get the thing that I got in the beginning with all the lines of code. If I get rid of the from findall line and put in `import re`, then I get a findall error

Comment: Like this? `import urllib.request
import re
from re import findall` Sorry, those are supposed to be a line each

Comment: It's sadly still the same thing as before with all the lines of code when I do that

Comment: I don't. I essentially would want of something like this: "Mikky Ekko - Time" to be printed. I really appreciated the help too, @vks!

Comment: Added for you, so hopefully, it helps!

Comment: @kakbar231 try now.no need to use `re.DOTALL`.See demo as well

Answer (score 0):

Use [lxml](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

```
import lxml.html

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(response.read())
for li in doc.findall('.//li'):
    print li.text_content()
```

Comment: I don't have the module, so it won't let me do it, even if I try to import it